# null passed as context to a function call

Tags: javascript

Please explain what hack is used here (I can see that null is passed as a context to a function returning a property of it's context. So I can't clearly understand what is actually happening here.

```JavaScript
function getGlobal(){   
  return (function(){   
    return this.dust;   
      }).call(null);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the context to null will make `this` pointing to the global object. So the code provided will act as accessing the `dust` property of the global object.

According to the specification of ECMA 262 v5, 10.4.3 Entering Function Code

```
if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
```

see http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use the fact that if you don't have a receiver of the function, `window` (in fact the global object of the executed script, hence the name) is used.

So this trick enables to bypass a property (`dust`) defined in the nearest embedding context and use the one defined in the global object.

Comment: Why not just use `window.dust` directly? Can global object sometimes not be window?

Comment: There is rarely a point, that's why such code is rare. A reason might be you're making a library that you want to be compatible with non browsers js engines (e.g. node.js) : then the global object isn't called `window`. But generally, when you make a library, you avoid accessing the global object...